# neovim doesn't change cursor in st terminal

Tags: cursor, st

I have recently started using st. But nvim doesn't change cursor shape like that in gnome-terminal or xfce4-terminal in this terminal. What's more confusing is that it works fine in tmux inside st!
I don't know anything about st. So, my question is, what's wrong?

Edit: Very, very, confusing observation. I didn't install st-terminal per se. I cloned and compiled and launched it from rofi menu. But if I launch st from another terminal like xfce4-terminal, it handles nvim cursor changes currectly, although a little slow!

Comment: What's the output of `echo $TERM` when you run it in st inside tmux and when you run it in st outside of tmux?

Comment: both output st-terminal. And please take a look at the post. I edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in the release after 0.2.2.  This was reported in [neovim/neovim#7641](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/7641) and the issue was that st's terminfo incorrectly specifies how to change the cursor shape.

The fix in neovim was to ignore what st reports and use the typical values for those escape sequences.

Comment: You were right. I don't know why `sudo apt update` didn't bring neovim updates. I had to manually reinstall it.

Comment: Just to be clear, 0.2.2 is the current release.  The next version (which has the fix I mentioned) hasn't been released yet, so reinstalling wouldn't have changed anything unless you're using the nightly PPA.

Comment: yes I'm using the dev  branch of neovim ppa. Thanks for reaching out.